# It is possible to use Pokemon images in a game?

Tags: legal, copyright, nintendo, intellectual-property

Is it possible to use Pokemon images, names, elements in a game I would like to make?
Are they still copyrighted, patented, would I get sued?

(Maybe their rights have expired by now, is what I am thinking?)

Comment: http://www.sloperama.com/advice/faq61.htm

Comment: I actually picked up a book that has art you can use that seem like they are like pokemon: http://www.amazon.com/500-Manga-Creatures-Yishan-Li/dp/0061650501

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Copyright expiry depends where you live. The simple answer is that they are copyright, and you can get sued. (More likely you'll get a cease-and-desist shutting down development of your game and threatening legal action.)

If you really want a pokemon-style game, create your own unique game world and characters and use those.

Answer (score 1):

Copyright protecion lasts for the life of author and 70 years based on the the longest living author if jointly created or if work of corporate authorship, works for hire, or anonymous and pseudonymous works, the shorter of 95 years from publication, or 120 years from creation.

Comment: ... in one country.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do because of the Straight of author. The only way is to contact the legal department of Game Freak and ask permission to use their works (sound, images, fonts and etc...)